# capacitor-community/NativeAudio not loading assets?

Tags: javascript, ios, capacitor

Trying to load audio files (mp3s) on an iOS app created with Capacitor.

I'm using the [Native Audio](https://github.com/capacitor-community/native-audio) community plugin as per their usage directions:

```js
NativeAudio.preloadSimple({
  assetPath: "assets/casual-loop1.mp3",
  assetId: "casual-loop1",
});
```

The `assets` directory lives in my project's `App/public` directory. And it does indeed contain the `casual-loop1.mp3` file. (Copied over via `npx cap copy`).

But when I compile my app in Xcode, I see the following in the console:

```
ERROR MESSAGE:  {"errorMessage":"","message":"Asset Path is missing"}
```

A bit of digging showed me that this is [the line](https://github.com/capacitor-community/native-audio/blob/57b9a8e4f4f3f3449f8e5ad0df9f2b29fb760405/ios/Plugin/Plugin.swift#L233) throwing the error. I'm not familiar enough with Swift to make heads or tails of it though.

Anyone know what's up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NativeAudio.preloadSimple({
          assetPath: "public/assets/casual-loop1.mp3",
          assetId: "casual-loop1",
        });
```

It works for me.